# Dynamically display content inside of a DIV with FOR loop

Tags: php, html

*Note on title:* I really did not know how to perfectly name this question. If someone can suggest a more appropriate title, please do.

Long story short: I need to display 9 child `<div>` tags inside one parent `<div>` tag.

If there are 11 `<div>` tags to display, I need to have 2 parent `<div>` tags with first having 9 child `<div>` and second 2 child `div>`.'

**functions.php:**

```
$display = 0;
$x = 0;

for ($divs=0; $divs < $total_divs; $divs++) { 
    echo '<div class="w3-display-container" style="height: 300px;">';

    for (; $x < count($test_cases); $x++) {

        if ($display > 8) {
            $display = 0;
        }

        echo '<div class="' . $displays[$display] . ' w3-padding">';
        echo '<form target="_blank" action="./test.php" method="get">';
        echo '<input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="' . $test_cases[$x] . '" name="test">';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';

        $display++;
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

**Problem**: Let's assume that there are 11 child `<div>`. Everything  works as excepted besides that all child `<div>` tags are output into first parent `<div>`. Second parent `<div>` is empty. I left a comment at the very bottom of the HTML script. As you can see, tenth and eleventh tags override first and second.

I need to display first 9 `<div>` in first parent `<div>`, and the remaining 2 `<div>` tags in second parent `<div>`. In order to achieve it, I need to output every child `<div>` tag after ninth into the second parent `<div>`. **How can I do that?**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-container w3-padding-32">
   <div class="w3-display-container" style="height: 300px;">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="first" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="second" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-topright w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="third" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-left w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="fourth" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-middle w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="fifth" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-right w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="sixth" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="seventh" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get">
        
        <input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="eigth" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="ninth" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="tenth" name="test-case"></form></div><div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-padding"><form target="_blank" action="./report.php" method="get"><input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="eleventh" name="test-case"></form></div></div>
        <!-- This div should contain tenth and eleventh child divs -->
        <div class="w3-display-container" style="height: 300px;"></div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: What if there is 18, or 21 divs?

Comment: Oh my God...I just solved it...Thanks for this reminder, I literally forgot that it has to be dynamic. Your comment switched my brain on. I just needed to break out of loop at the right time. This is what happens when you work 24/7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to break out of inner loop at the right time:

```
$display = 0;
$x = 0;

for ($divs=0; $divs < $total_divs; $divs++) { 
    echo '<div class="w3-display-container" style="height: 300px;">';

    for (; $x < count($test_cases);) {

        if ($display > 8) {
            $display = 0;
        }

        echo '<div class="' . $displays[$display] . ' w3-padding">';
        echo '<form target="_blank" action="./test.php" method="get">';
        echo '<input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="' . $test_cases[$x] . '" name="test">';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';

        $x++;
        $display++;

        // Solution
        if ($x !== 0 && $x % 9 === 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is actually a bad answer. You should make your answer more clear for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Split your divs array in chunks with array_splice and loop the new array.

I first calculate the remaining of a mod on 9.
In this case 2.
Then if $rem is not zero I add take those two items and add them to $chunks.
Then loop until all items has been moved to $chunks.

Then  I just need to do a nested foreach to echo them.

```
$divs = range(1,11);

$rem = count($divs)%9;
if($rem) $chunks[] = array_splice($divs,0,$rem);
while(count($divs)){
    $chunks[] = array_splice($divs,0,9);
}

foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    echo "<div>\n";
    foreach($chunk as $div){
        echo "    <div>" . $div . "</div>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/dfdfk

Answer (score 0):

Unclear of somethings going on here but chunking the divs into a group of nine and remaining seems correct

```
<?php

// boundary
$b = 9;
// number of divs
$div_cnt = 12;
// make an array of placeholder (just for demo)
$divs = array_fill(0, $div_cnt, 1);
// split divs into chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($divs, $b);
// loop over chunks
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    // ignore if chunk has less than 2 items
    if(count($chunk) < 2) continue;
    // print the first div
    echo '<div class="w3-display-container" style="height: 300px;">';
    // remove first item (probably want to do something with it)
    array_shift($chunk);
    // set index
    $i = 0;
    // loop over remaining
    foreach($chunk as $c) {
        echo '<div class="' . $displays[$o] . ' w3-padding">';
        echo '<form target="_blank" action="./test.php" method="get">';
        echo '<input type="Submit" class="w3-button w3-hover-gray w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-round-xlarge w3-xlarge" value="' . $test_cases[$i] . '" name="test">';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$total  = 3; // total inner divs.
$chunks = 2; // amount of inner divs in each div sandwich

for (
    $outer_limit = ceil($total / $chunks), $parent = 0, $counter = 0;
    $parent < $outer_limit;
    $parent++
) { 
    echo "<div class='outer'>\n";
    for (
        $child = 0;
        $child < $chunks && $counter < $total;
        $child++, $counter++
    ) {
        echo "\t<div class='inner'>\n";
        printf(
            "\t\tParent: %d, Child: %d, Counter: %d\n",
            $parent,
            $child,
            $counter
        );
        echo "\t</div>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'>
        Parent: 0, Child: 0, Counter: 0
    </div>
    <div class='inner'>
        Parent: 0, Child: 1, Counter: 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'>
        Parent: 1, Child: 0, Counter: 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        define("INTERVAL",9);
        function html_div($total_divs)
        {
                $close = "";
                for($case = 0; $case< $total_divs;++$case)
                {
                        $display = $case % INTERVAL; // 0.. 8, print every 0th time
                        if (0 == $display) // true on every 9th div
                                echo "${close}\n<DIV CLASS = \"container\">\n";
                        echo "<div class=\"${display}\" value=\"${case}\"></div>\n";
                        if (0 == $case)
                                $close = "</DIV>";
                }
                echo "${close}\n";
        }

        html_div(23);
        html_div(0);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<DIV CLASS = "container">
<div class="0" value="0"></div>
<div class="1" value="1"></div>
<div class="2" value="2"></div>
<div class="3" value="3"></div>
<div class="4" value="4"></div>
<div class="5" value="5"></div>
<div class="6" value="6"></div>
<div class="7" value="7"></div>
<div class="8" value="8"></div>
</DIV>
<DIV CLASS = "container">
<div class="0" value="9"></div>
<div class="1" value="10"></div>
<div class="2" value="11"></div>
<div class="3" value="12"></div>
<div class="4" value="13"></div>
<div class="5" value="14"></div>
<div class="6" value="15"></div>
<div class="7" value="16"></div>
<div class="8" value="17"></div>
</DIV>
<DIV CLASS = "container">
<div class="0" value="18"></div>
<div class="1" value="19"></div>
<div class="2" value="20"></div>
<div class="3" value="21"></div>
<div class="4" value="22"></div>
</DIV>
```